# Trying to install Magick-Rotation on a gateway C-140x

Tags: tablet, touchscreen, wacom

Hello I'm hoping I can get some help here. I have a gateway C-140xl and I just upgraded to 14.04. I'm trying to install magick-rotation 1.6.2. First issue I noticed is that the installer is recognized as and installer. So I read the manual install instructions I get through it except for the part where it Unity Tray whitelist. Try to follow the instruction with either the dconf-editor or gsetting method and both won't work. I'm new to Ubuntu and don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. I'm just trying to find a simple way to get the screen rotation to work on this tablet.